# How to use different NSSortDescriptor for different sections of NSFetchedResultsController? (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have simple UITableView app with 1 Core Data entity and NSFetchedResultsController. I have 2 sections that split automatically by FRC:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "finished", ascending: true)
let sortByStartDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "endDate", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortByStartDate]<br/>
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "finished", cacheName: nil)
```

In the ViewController:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}
```

This sort both sections by [sortDescriptor, sortByStartDate].

**QUESTION:** 
What is the most simple approach (I'm newbie in programming) to sort second section by another NSSortDescriptor or just sort differently?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you deal with items that are not finished yet. If they have an `endDate` that's `NULL` they have no relative sorting. So you could add a third sort descriptor on the fetch request for sorting in the second section.

Otherwise I would change the setup to use a second `NSFetchedResultsController` so you have one for each section. Use a predicate on both to filter on `finished == true` or `finished == false`.